# How to merge two #js maps in Om Clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript, om

In clojurescript when I merge two maps I can do it like this:

```
(merge {:a 1} {:b 2})
```

How can I achieve a similar thing in Om, where literals are used, something like this (which doesn't work):

```
(merge #js {:a 1} #js {:b 2})
```

Comment: Can you merge them before turning into js? eg `(clj->js (merge {:a 1} {:b 2}))`

Comment: Ok, thanks (clj->js (merge {:a 1} {:b 2})) worked! :)

Comment: @Dan, you should answer the question so you can get credit and make it easier to see the answer

Comment: @Nathan, yes thanks, if he answers it I will mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

You can merge them as you normally and then use `clj->js` to convert the result into javascript:

`(clj->js (merge {:a 1} {:b 2}))`